# How to create a button that starts WiFi direct

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I have no prior experience with app development and am now supposed to create an app in android studio that connects to a sensor by WiFi-direct. I have read up on WiFi-direct and tried to follow the guides https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html and https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html but when using their code I have still no clue how to move forward. I have also looked at several demo apps for WiFi direct.

My code looks like this at the moment.

Broadcast reciever:

```
public class WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private WifiP2pManager mManager;
private WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;
private MainActivity mActivity;

public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, WifiP2pManager.Channel channel,
                                   MainActivity activity) {
    super();
    this.mManager = manager;
    this.mChannel = channel;
    this.mActivity = activity;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        // Check to see if Wi-Fi is enabled and notify appropriate activity
        int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
        if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
            mActivity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mActivity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(false);
        }

    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        // Call WifiP2pManager.requestPeers() to get a list of current peers
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        // Respond to new connection or disconnections
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        // Respond to this device's wifi state changing
    }
}
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WifiP2pManager mManager;
WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;
private boolean isWifiP2pEnabled = false;
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
IntentFilter mIntentFilter;


public void setIsWifiP2pEnabled(boolean isWifiP2pEnabled) {
    this.isWifiP2pEnabled = isWifiP2pEnabled;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);


    mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
    mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
    mReceiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(mManager, mChannel, this);

}

/* register the broadcast receiver with the intent values to be matched */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mReceiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(mManager, mChannel, this);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
}
/* unregister the broadcast receiver */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}



}
```

The next part in the guide is that I should try to discover peers. Where should I implement this code?

```
mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        // Code for when the discovery initiation is successful goes here.
        // No services have actually been discovered yet, so this method
        // can often be left blank.  Code for peer discovery goes in the
        // onReceive method, detailed below.
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
        // Code for when the discovery initiation fails goes here.
        // Alert the user that something went wrong.
    }
});
```

My final product should be a button that when I press it I should search for peers and be able to connect to one. The sensor will boot in WiFi direct. Does anyone know where I can find more info on how to proceed or have tips on what classes I need and such?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The way it works is by:

- Calling `discoverPeers` when tapping on the button
- Next, in your `WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver` -> `WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION` condition, request the list of available peers like this: `mManager.requestPeers(mChannel, peerListListener);`
- Then, you have to implement `WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener` in your activity or fragment because the discovered peers will return into this method:

  `@Override
  public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peerList) {}`
- Once you have the list of peers, you can connect to any peer using 
  `mManager.connect(mChannel, config, new ActionListener() {});`

I believe following https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html is good enough to get the api working.

Goodluck.

Comment: thank you!  Should i request the list of peers in the OnRecieve method or create a seperate method like "public void DiscoverPeers()" or something?

Comment: Yes, inside the "OnReceive" where the comment says requestPeers --> else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        // Call WifiP2pManager.requestPeers() to get a list of current peers
    }